# Merge two tables in python (using pandas) where the link depends on uniqueness

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Suppose I have two tables

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

first_table = pd.DataFrame({'key1': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                            'key2': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'],
                            'key3': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
                            'value_first': range(6)})
second_table = pd.DataFrame({'key1': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
                            'key2': [np.nan, np.nan, 'a', 'a', 'b'],
                            'key3': [np.nan, np.nan, 'A', 'B', np.nan],
                            'value_second': [6, 4, 2, 0, -2]})
```

so the first table looks like this

```
   key1 key2 key3  value_first
0     1    a    A            0
1     2    a    A            1
2     2    a    B            2
3     2    b    A            3
4     3    a    A            4
5     3    b    A            5
```

while the second table looks like this

```
   key1 key2 key3  value_second
0     1  NaN  NaN             6
1     1  NaN  NaN             4
2     2    a    A             2
3     2    a    B             0
4     3    b  NaN            -2
```

Now I want an outer merge of `first_table` and `second_table` based on the three keys. Note that the second table is not unique based on the three keys but the first are. Hence `key2` and `key3` is not necessary when `key1` is unique in the first table. In the same way `key3` is not necessary when the first two keys are unique in combination.

If the second table were proberly filled in then the merge would be straightforward by

```
pd.merge(first_table, second_table, 
         how='outer', 
         left_on=['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], 
         right_on=['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
```

but how do I get the desired result in this case? The desired result looks like this

```
   key1 key2 key3  value_first  value_second
0   1    a    A          0.0           6.0
1   1    a    A          0.0           4.0
2   2    a    A          1.0           2.0
3   2    a    B          2.0           0.0
4   2    b    A          3.0           NaN
5   3    a    A          4.0           NaN
6   3    b    A          5.0          -2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to first merge the dataframes just on `key1`, then fill the `NaN` with respective values from first table, then drop rows when values are different, and finally merge with the first table again to get the remaining rows (where `value_second=NaN`).

```
df = pd.merge(first_table, second_table, left_on=['key1'], right_on=['key1'], how='outer')
df['key2_y'] = df['key2_y'].fillna(df['key2_x'])
df['key3_y'] = df['key3_y'].fillna(df['key3_x'])
df = df[(df['key2_x'] == df['key2_y']) & (df['key3_x'] == df['key3_y'])]
df.drop(['key2_y', 'key3_y'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df = pd.merge(first_table, df, left_on=['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'value_first'], 
              right_on=['key1', 'key2_x', 'key3_x', 'value_first'], how='outer')
df.drop(['key2_x', 'key3_x'], axis=1, inplace=True)

       key1 key2 key3  value_first  value_second
0     1    a    A            0           6.0
1     1    a    A            0           4.0
2     2    a    A            1           2.0
3     2    a    B            2           0.0
4     2    b    A            3           NaN
5     3    a    A            4           NaN
6     3    b    A            5          -2.0
```